# add class to div from another button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class to div while I have already a button that is doing it. but i can't figure out the code and how to set it up on the button.

I tried calling the class ith the button such as onclick="class="class name"

but it doesent work

define(function () {
    App.Exist(".social-wrapper") && (App.Query(".social-wrapper").onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(),
                function (e, s) {
                    var t = document.documentElement;
                    if ((s = s || {
                            resizable: 1,
                            scrollbars: 1,
                            width: 500,
                            height: 550
                        }).height && void 0 === s.top) {
                        var n = void 0 !== window.screenTop ? window.screenTop : screen.top,
                            a = screen.height || window.innerHeight || t.clientHeight;
                        s.top = parseInt((a - s.height) / 2, 10) + n
                    }
                    if (s.width && void 0 === s.left) {
                        var i = void 0 !== window.screenLeft ? window.screenLeft : screen.left,
                            o = screen.width || window.innerWidth || t.clientWidth;
                        s.left = parseInt((o - s.width) / 2, 10) + i
                    }
                    var c = [];
                    Object.keys(s).forEach(function (e) {
                        var t = s[e];
                        c.push(e + (null !== t ? "=" + t : ""))
                    });
                    var r = window.open(e, "_blank", c.join(","));
                    r && r.focus && r.focus()
                }(e.target.href)
        }),
        function () {
            var t = App.Query;

```
        function s(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), o.remClass("is-selected"), c.remClass("is-selected"), l.remClass("selected"), a.addClass("is-visible"), i.addClass("is-selected"), r.addClass("selected")
        }

        function n(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), i.remClass("is-selected"), c.remClass("is-selected"), r.remClass("selected"), a.addClass("is-visible"), o.addClass("is-selected"), l.addClass("selected")
        }
        var a = t(".cd-user-modal"),
            i = t("#cd-login", a),
            o = t("#cd-signup", a),
            c = t("#cd-reset-password", a),
            e = t(".cd-switcher"),
            r = t("a", e)[0],
            l = t("a", e)[1],
            d = t(".cd-form-bottom-message a", i),
            p = t(".cd-form-bottom-message a", c),
            g = t(".top-bar-right");
        g.onclick = function (e) {
            e.target === g && t("ul", g).forEach(function (e) {
                e.toggleClass("is-visible")
            })
        }, t(".cd-signup").onclick = n, $(".cd-signin").on("click", s), a.onclick = function (e) {
            (e.target == a || e.target.classList.contains(".cd-close-form")) && a.remClass("is-visible")
        }, document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
            "27" == e.which && a.remClass("is-visible")
        }), e.onclick = function (e) {
            e.target === r ? s(e) : n(e)
        }, t(".hide-password").forEach(function (e) {
            e.onclick = function () {
                var e = this.previousElementSibling;
                "password" == e.getAttribute("type") ? e.setAttribute("type", "text") : e.setAttribute("type", "password"), this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML == Lang.get("show") ? Lang.get("hide") : Lang.get("show")
            }
        }), d.onclick = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(), i.remClass("is-selected"), o.remClass("is-selected"), c.addClass("is-selected")
        }, p.onclick = s
    }();
var s = App.Path.Func,
    n = function (e, t) {
        switch (e) {
            case "error":
                App.Info("error", Lang.get("an_error_occured"), t);
                break;
            case "errors":
                App.Info("error", Lang.get("notification"), t);
                break;
            case "logging":
                App.Info("success", Lang.get("please_wait"), Lang.get("logging_in"), 3e3);
                break;
            case "activated":
                App.xModal.show(Lang.get("account_activated"), Lang.get("account_activated_msg"));
                break;
            case "passreset":
                App.xModal.show(Lang.get("notification"), Lang.get("pass_changed"));
                break;
            case "welcome":
                App.xModal.show(Lang.get("vfc_head"), Lang.get("vfc_body"));
                break;
            case "passform":
                App.xModal.show(Lang.get("check_email"), Lang.get("activation_send"));
                break;
            case "reset_info":
                App.xModal.show(Lang.get("check_email"), Lang.get("forgot_send"))
        }
    },
    a = function (e, t) {
        return t || App.Loading(Lang.get("please_wait")), App.Request("post", s, e)
    },
    i = function (e, t) {
        for (var s in t) e[s] = t[s];
        return e
    },
    t = {
        Modal: App.Find(".cd-user-modal")
    },
    o = function (e) {
        t.Modal.click(), e.target.reset()
    };
({
    init: function () {
        document.addEventListener("submit", this, !1), -1 !== window.location.href.indexOf("/auth?") && this.Activate()
    },
    handleEvent: function (e) {
        if ("submit" === e.type) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = App.ParseForm.call(e.target);
            switch (e.target.id) {
                case "logForm":
                    this.Login(e, i(t.Data, {
                        auth_type: "login"
                    }));
                    break;
                case "regForm":
                    this.Register(e, i(t.Data, {
                        auth_type: "signup"
                    }));
                    break;
                case "resetForm":
                    this.Reset(e, i(t.Data, {
                        auth_type: "reset"
                    }));
                    break;
                case "newPass":
                    this.NewPass(e, i(t.Data, {
                        auth_type: "newpass"
                    }))
            }
        }
    },
    NewPass: function (e, t) {
        a(t).then(function (e) {
            App.Loading("close"), 1 == e ? n("passreset") : n("errors", e)
        })
    },
    Register: function (t, e) {
        a(e).then(function (e) {
            App.Loading("close"), 1 == e ? (n("welcome"), o(t)) : n("errors", e)
        })
    },
    Reset: function (t, e) {
        a(e).then(function (e) {
            App.Loading("close"), 2 == e ? (n("passform"), o(t)) : 1 == e ? (n("reset_info"), o(t)) : n("errors", e)
        })
    },
    Login: function (t, e) {
        a(e).then(function (e) {
            App.Loading("close"), 1 == e ? (o(t), n("logging"), setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload()
            }, 2500)) : n("error", e)
        })
    },
    Activate: function () {
        a({
            auth_type: "activation",
            code: window.location.href.split("?").pop()
        }, 1).then(function (e) {
            "success" == e ? n("activated") : "active" == e && (window.location.href = Conf.get("app_url"))
        })
    }
}).init()
```

});

The button needs to change an existing div class name

Comment: I am trying to call: "cd-user-modal" to be "cd-user-modal is visible"

Comment: Please use Markdown to style all your code snippets.  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I do not know what in the code is relevant  for the answer i did not write it